# Flutter: show another value when value is null

Tags: android, flutter

I have an app which has a list and when its empty it shows "null", but i wanted to show nothing instead of it but i can't.
I have tried to make a verification but it still showing null for some reason.

Here is the code:

```
   child: Text(
                                  produtosList1.isEmpty ||
                                          produtosList1[index].qtd == "" ||
                                          produtosList1[index].qtd == null
                                      ? " " 
                                      : produtosList1[index].qtd,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
```

But here is how it shows:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this check also to your `||`  `produtosList1[index].qtd == "null"`.

Your app is displaying `null` and not an empty string `""` because most likely the value in `qtd` is a `String "null"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable that can be `null` you can do this to show something else instead of it:
`produtosList1[index].qtd ?? 'Instead of null'`.

`??` returns the expression on its left unless that expression’s value is null, in which case it evaluates and returns the expression on its right.